# Setting an object to a random position in the BGE

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I'm programming a game, and I have an empty that I want to be dropping enemies randomly throughout the map.  I have the following logic bricks and Python script right now:

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    sens = cont.sensors['mySensor']

    if sens.positive:
        own.worldPosition = [own['xPos'], own['yPos'], 30]

main()
```

[image: logic bricks]

My empty is staying in the same place, but it is at least adding enemies every second.  How can I make the empty go to the random positions that are being generated by random actuator (I would have used the random module but it wasn't working last time I tried it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your script controller is on the `Enemy Dropper` object and attempts to reference `mySensor` which does not exist on that object. If you check the console, accessed by *Window* > *Toggle System Console* (only on windows systems), you will see an error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "Setting Position.py", line 9, in 
>   KeyError: 'value = gameOb[key]: KX_GameObject, key "mySensor" does not exist'
>   Python script error - object 'Enemy Dropper', controller 'Python':

To make it operable, add the `mySensor` sensor to the `Enemy Dropper` object's logic bricks.

Answer (score 1):

using only the python script (delete the properties and the edit object actuator ) :

import random

```
def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    sense = cont.sensors["mySensor"]
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

    if sense.positive :
        own.worldPosition=[random.uniform(-10.0,10.0),random.uniform(-10.0,10.0),0]
        scene.addObject("Cube", "Empty", 0)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a navmesh, and then loop through vertices and pick one on the nav mesh, and then do ray checks , so you know the actor will fit.

```
import bge
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentConroller()
own = cont.owner

mesh = own.meshes[0]
```

this will get you started down the path, check the python api and let me know if you need more help then this.

own.castRay(To,From,Distance,'property',NormalReturnType,Xray,PolyData)
bge.logic.getCurrentScene().addObject('object',object_to_add_@,time)